# Use apply suite to perform a function using multiple columns on certain rows of a data frame based on the values in one column

Tags: r, apply

I want to perform a function - that uses multiple columns - on certain rows of a data frame based on the contents in one column.  I can, of course, accomplish this task using a simple for loop, but I am sure that it must be possible to do so more elegantly using one of the apply functions.  I just can't quite figure it out.

```
(data <- data.frame(a = sample(10), b = sample(10), c=NA))

# for every value of b that is greater than 5, 
# set c to be equal to a function of a and b, say: 3 * a + b
# otherwise, c = a

for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  if(data$b[i] > 5) {
    data$c[i] <- 3*data$a[i]+data$b[i]
  } else {
    data$c[i] <- data$a[i]
  }
}

data
```

I realize that there are three things going on here: (1) figuring out which rows to perform the function on, (2) performing the function on those rows and (3) performing the alternate function on the other rows.  If I could figure out how to apply a function using multiple columns to every row, I could subset the data before I did that.

I thought that code like this would allow me to perform a function using multiple columns:

```
sapply(data$b, function(b, a) 3*a+b, a=data$a) 
#or
lapply(data$b, function(b, a) 3*a+b, a=data$a)
```

But it returns an nxn matrix of numbers (or n lists that are n long), and I can't figure out how it calculated them.

I also suspect it's possible to do the selection and the function at the same time (maybe with code like this:

```
data$c <- sapply(data$b, function(b, table) 3*table$a[b>5] + b[b>5], table=data)
```

)
But that code results in similar output problems.

I think most of my problems stem from the fact that I am not quite comfortable with the apply functions, especially with multiple arguments, but none of my fiddling has enlightened me.

Thank you!

Comment: `ifelse(data$b > 5, 3 * data$a + data$b, data$a)` is the most straightforward way. It's vectorized and uses conditions.

Comment: Thank you!  That solution is both simple and perfect!

Answer (score 2):

You can use plyr:ddply (easiest for me) if you need to run functions rowwise

In this example as Blue Magister describes, probably easier to do it directly as:

```
data$c<-ifelse(data$b > 5, 3 * data$a + data$b, data$a)
```

But here's a ddply example

```
require(plyr)
ddply(data, c("a","b"), function(df)ifelse(df$b>5,df$a+df$b,df$a))
```

or

```
data<-adply(data,1,transform,c=ifelse(b>5,a+b,b))
```

Or obviously in this case you can just use apply:

```
data$c<-apply(data, 1, function(x)ifelse(x["b"]>5,x["a"]+x["b"],x["a"]))
```

Comment: Thank you!  I've been meaning to learn plyr - this is a good start.